# How do you handle temporary nuget package updates in git

Tags: c#, git, nuget

It's not an uncommon occurrence for me to have the need to make a change to one of our nugets and consume it within the same git branch.  When actually pushing the change, this is unavoidably annoying, but I deal with it.

However, when I'm developing the nuget package, I'll often have to build and consume from a local, on-disk repository.  This results in many modifications to .csproj and package.config files that are ultimately not needed.  Where this becomes the biggest problem is when I actually have changes to those files that are needed.

The best work around I've come up with for this is to stage all my changes prior to updating packages, so all my good changes are staged and all my temp changes are not.  But this only goes so far, as eventually I'm going to make more changes that will need to be staged.  What would be really nice is if there was a way to "quarantine" the changes made by the nuget update, so they're there, but not a part of my actual dev changes.

Is there a good way to handle temporary changes like this, so I can keep my good changes free of unnecessary package updates?

Comment: Are you talking about many changes to your project files (which result in many local git commits) or many revisions of the nugets?

Comment: Your package should have all the unit and integration testing that's needed to prove that your changes work so you don't have to do local references from the real application. The only reason to have to iterate on package deployment is if there's a problem with the packaging process.

Comment: If the package is the same repo, make all the changes to the package in a separate branch from the one where those changes need to be consumed.

Comment: @madreflection or in a worktree!  That's a good idea.